# Does the C++ standard explicitly allow/disallow instantiating std::function with incomplete types?

Tags: c++, types, std-function

Consider something like this:

```
class A;

std::function<A(A)> f;
```

This is clearly something you want to do in your program. Any major compiler accepts that without problems.

My question is: is it technically allowed by the standard?

If I see correctly, the section

> 20.5.4.8 Other functions

prohibits use of template parameters of incomplete type at instantiation, unless otherwise specified (and not only for containers).

In the section about `std::function` or `<functional>` I see no reference to allowing this.

Does somebody know where and if this is explicitly written in the standard?

Comment: From the "latest" version of the standard: *"[...] the effects are undefined [...]"*. [res.on.functions](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.functions). So I think there are no requirements on the implementation, it may accept that

Answer (score 2):

This is covered by the library catch-all [[res.on.functions]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.functions)

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: [...]
>
> - if an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Since nothing in [[func.wrap.func]](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func) overrides this, it is undefined behavior to have an incomplete function type.

As an example of what an you would need to see in [func.wrap.func] lets look at [[unique.ptr]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#4)

> [...] The template parameter T of unique_­ptr may be an incomplete type.

Here it explicitly states that an incomplete type is allowed.  We would need something like that in [func.wrap.func] and we don't, so we fall back to [res.on.functions]/2 and it being undefined behavior.

Comment: This was my suspicion. Should all major compilers warn (e.g. GCC with pedantic), or should it be allowed in the standard? I see a minor defect here, either from compilers or from the standard. (Along the lines of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4371.html)

Comment: @FilippoL Well, in case of undefined behavior is not required to emit a warning

Comment: @FilippoL Per [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.compliance#1) the compiler is not required to diagnose undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver are we sure this is an actual UB? Doesn't the standard let the compiler the choice to accept the code as valid (without UB)?

Comment: @BiagioFesta [res.on.functions]/2 says **the effects are undefined**

Comment: What about this sentence:
`A callable type F is Lvalue-Callable for argument types ArgTypes and return type R if the expression INVOKE<R>(declval<F&>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...), considered as an unevaluated operand, is well-formed`

And `[expr.context]`:
`In some contexts, unevaluated operands appear [...]
An unevaluated operand is not evaluated.
[ Note: In an unevaluated operand, a non-static class member may be named ([expr.prim.id]) and naming of objects or functions does not, by itself, require that a definition be provided ([basic.def.odr]).`

Comment: @FilippoL That doesn't help.  It explicitly states *is well-formed* and it is not well-formed per [res.on.functions]/2.  There needs to be an explicit *incomplete type is allowed*, and there isn't, so it isnt.